# Html required attribute set as not required

Tags: html, webforms

I have some code as below:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="datepicker">Date of Birth</label>
<div class="col-sm-8" ><input class="form-control col-sm-10" type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" required="true" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['DOB'])) echo $_SESSION['DOB'] ?>"></div>
```

My issue is that I don't want this "Date of Birth" field to be a required field anymore.  How do I set this field as unrequired?

I have tried setting `required="false"` but this does not work.

Any advice much appreciated, many thanks
Jean-Claude

Comment: remove the `required` field

Comment: check this fiddle with required and not required field https://jsfiddle.net/T29Kx/374/

Comment: Of course, that is simple I don't know why I hadn't thought of this.
Well removing the required field allows me to proceed through the form without entering the fields where I have removed required but it returns an error when i try to submit the form:

*Date of Birth is required*
*Address is required*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The required attribute does not take the attribute value. It's just required="true", or required="required", or just setting the

```
<input type="text" required />
```

would make it required as well. Just unset the required attribute. If you're trying to unset it after some user action (with javascript) then use the
[.removeAttribute("required")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="datepicker">Date of Birth</label>
<div class="col-sm-8" ><input class="form-control col-sm-10" type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['DOB'])) echo $_SESSION['DOB'] ?>"></div>
```

Avoid using **required** if you don't need them.

***Also the attributes that are not necessary must be avoided.***